# Why my ListFragment's onListItemClick can't be triggered?

Tags: android, listview, contacts

I am working on android 4.03's Contacts, in CallLogFragment(extend from ListFragment):

I overrides onListItemClick in CallLogFragment, I want the frameworks call onListItemClick.
But it didn't call. After view the source code, I found that the item view's sub view has been set the onclickListenner in CallLogAdapter:

```
private void findAndCacheViews(View view) {
    // Get the views to bind to.
    CallLogListItemViews views = CallLogListItemViews.fromView(view);
    views.primaryActionView.setOnClickListener(mPrimaryActionListener);
    views.secondaryActionView.setOnClickListener(mSecondaryActionListener);
    view.setTag(views);
}
```

The CallLogListItemViews is the item view in ListView, the primaryActionView is the member class view in CallLogListItemViews, when I click the item in ListView, the ListFragment's onListItemClick can't be triggered, but the callback function(mPrimaryActionListener) was triggered. How should I do that the onListItemClick can be triggered when I click the item?
Thanks very much!